# Docker Time Drift on macOS

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I've been experiencing time drifts on my docker containers, which are running on a mac (v10.13.4):

[image: Docker Version]

An app is executing code like the following:

```
var waitTime = InitialWaitTime;
while(condition) 
{
    Log($"Waiting for {waitTime}");
    await Task.Delay(waitTime, cancelToken);
    waitTime = await TimeSensitiveTask(cancelToken);
}

void Log(string message) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.UtcNow:o}] {message}");
}
```

After having the app running for hours, using `docker logs -t container_name` shows logs with dates in the future.

A consequence of the time drift is that the `TimeSensitiveTask` fails due to it being executed ahead of time. I do have a retry policy so after waiting for more time it eventually succeeds, the more time the app has been running the earlier the execution happens.

Logging into the container and printing the current time also shows the time drift by printing a time in the future.

```
docker exec -t <container_name> date -u && date -u
Fri May 25 14:28:16 UTC 2018
Fri May 25 14:26:34 UTC 2018
```

It's my understanding that the native versions of docker for mac should not have this issue. What can I do to solve this?

I've already tried resetting docker to factory and completely uninstalling/reinstalling docker.

Comment: Please include which OS you're on how you are using docker (directly, docker-machine, docker-for-mac etc.). There's e.g. https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/17

Comment: Also note that task.Delay is not a proper scheduler if you want a specific interval, It will give you an interval in between the time that the `TimeSensitiveTask` takes.

Comment: What is `Log`? Can you show its implementation?

Comment: And if the time drifts without your code involved, then this might not be a C# related question at all, and a docker-only question.

Comment: And you're saying that you understand that the native versions of docker mac should not have this issue, why/how are you understanding this? Do you have a link about this? I found this: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2076 - is this the issue you're seeing?

Comment: And just to be clear, `await Task.Delay` is not accurate, so if you're building your timing code yourself, and not using the clock, then you're bound to drift one way or the other. For instance, if `Task.Delay(1000)` consistently waits just a few milliseconds shorter, then eventually you'll have drifted enough for it to matter. However, if you can see the drift by asking the docker container what the time is inside it, and that has drifted, then it seems that is what the github issue above covers.

Comment: Yes, await Task.Delay is not accurate, this is not a prod app, just a test I've been doing. Thing is the time drift still happens, the .NET code actually has nothing to do with the problem, that just happens to be the code running... thinking of actually removing it from the question as it appears to be adding noise.

Comment: I've read many github issues where it's stated that the issue has been fixed, the link provided by @MartinUllrich is an example.

Comment: I'd not seen the issue shared by @LasseVågsætherKarlsen that is still open. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved in version v18.06.0-ce of Docker.